# cannot run android ddms in visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

as I say I cannot run android ddms in visual studio 2015 in android app with xamarin shared project, when I click Open Android Device Monitor (DDMS) I have a message 'Ann error is occure. See the log file: ... '.

Also in xamarin log i have this:
'[W:]:    Adb connection refused'

Is it possible that it happen because I transfer android sdk folder to another partition? I changed android sdk location in xamarin options.

[xamarin tutorial that I'm following at msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn879698.aspx)

[log file onedrive link](http://1drv.ms/1UW2vOX)

Comment: Are you running VS 2015 as admin?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the cmd with admin privileges.
2. Run `cd C:\Users`
3. Run `mklink /D "Your%20User" "Your User"`

EDIT: Change this folder to writable:

> C:\Users\Adam%20Skibicki\.android\monitor-workspace\.metadata

Comment: it shows: 'C:\Users>mklink /D "Adam%20Skibicki" "Adam Skibicki"
Nie można utworzyć pliku, który już istnieje.' - it means it cannot create file which already exist

Comment: "The folder "C:\Users\Adam%20Skibicki\.android\monitor-workspace\.metadata" is read-only." Change it to be also writable.

Comment: i cannot find .android folder in this location

Comment: Open it by `cmd` using `explorer C:\Users\Adam%20Skibicki\.android\monitor-workspace\.metadata`

Comment: it opens my documents

Comment: Open that folder properties and deselect the propriety "Read-only" and be sure that you are running VS as admin.

Comment: thanks i've done it and run as admin and it works ;)

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine in the Visual Studio 2019. Click on the button **Open Android Device Monitor (DDMS)** as per image below:

[image]

I hope it helps.